# OkHttp3 logging interceptor does not log cookies

Tags: okhttp

I'm using OkHttp 3 (with retrofit2) and I'm trying to get both cookies and logging to work. The problem is the log shows everything but not the cookies. I have captured the HTTP traffic and the cookie ARE being sent, they are just not logged. I tried debugging the logging interceptor, and indeed, the request appears to have no cookies (although it does have other custom headers) when it reaches the `intercept()` call. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

```
    final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat(JSON_DATE_FORMAT)
            .create();

    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
    cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);

    OkHttpClient.Builder okClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request request = chain
                        .request()
                        .newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("custom-header", Utils.getRandomUUIDForHeader())
                        .build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        })
        .cookieJar(new JavaNetCookieJar(cookieManager))
        .addInterceptor(logging);

    if (mock) {
        okClientBuilder.addInterceptor(new MockApiInterceptor(context));
    }

    return new Retrofit
            .Builder()
            .baseUrl(serverURL)
            .client(okClientBuilder.build())
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build()
            .create(DefaultApi.class);
```

Sample output:

```
<-- 200 OK http://localhost:53580/login (31ms)
Content-Length: 66
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=4b42fc452e6adc55334e65b945c24b8886b127a57786a6cd51de6b3117a58cc9; Path=/
OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1467298601713
OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1467298601718

{
  "status":"OK",
  "sessionId":"p8tvdIHxQaON",
  "entities":[]
}
<-- END HTTP (66-byte body)
--> GET http://localhost:53580/data http/1.1
custom-header: 663d0354-8a16-471a-bf6d-fb7fdb3d3404
--> END GET
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The logging interceptor runs before cookies have been added to the request. Work around this by using a network interceptor instead of an application interceptor. More guidance is here:

https://square.github.io/okhttp/features/interceptors/

Comment: Link is not properly working anymore. New link: https://square.github.io/okhttp/interceptors/